# Android AlarmManager fires only once

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm creating an application where you have the option to set daily notifications at a customizable time. You flick a switch, a time picker dialog comes up, and if you pick a time, an AlarmManager is set up, but it fires only once - at the correct time, but only once.

I've dug through StackOverflow but can't seem to find anything useful. 
Here's the relevant part of my code (you can find the rest [here](https://github.com/Rastamas/WarhammerQuoteOfTheDay/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/rastamas/warhammerquoteoftheday)):

```
mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) SettingsActivity.this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SettingsActivity.this,
                0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Calendar calendar = getTimeForNotification();
if(shouldHaveAlreadyNotified(calendar)){
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, alarmPendingIntent);
```

Comment: Try this: `mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, ...);`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it to `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAK‌​EUP` made it that no notifications were made at all. Changing it to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` fixed the issue!

Thanks for anyone who suggested solutions.